# Why are only some attributes updated from my javascript function?

Tags: javascript

I have a button script to change the buttons in a frame based on the page loaded in the main frame. The problem I'm experiencing is that while the background images, tabindex and text on the button (innerHTML) all change as expected, the onclick doesn't. It appears to completely ignore it. Here's the script I'm using:

```
function createbutton(btn_N, btn_I, btn_L, btn_D) // (Div Name, Tab Index, Button Text, Page To Load){
    var btnN = top.frames['buttonbar'].document.getElementById(btn_N);

    btnN.style.cssText = "display:block; cursor:pointer; padding-left:16px; padding-top:5px;";
    btnN.onmouseover = function() {this.style.backgroundImage = "url('./osdimages/navBG_roll.png')";};
    btnN.onmouseout = function() {this.style.backgroundImage = '';};
    btnN.tabindex = btn_I;
    btnN.innerHTML = btn_L;
    btnN.onclick = btn_D;
}
```

The button call looks like this:

```
createbutton("button01", 1, "New Order/Browse",  "parent.frames['content'].location.href='createorder/createorder.asp';");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a difference between *attributes* and *properties*.

The best example of this is as follows:

- HTML: `<input type="text" value="hello" id="test" />`
- Type something in the text box
- `document.getElementById('test').value` is whatever you typed
- `document.getElementById('test').getAttribute("value")` is whatever was in the HTML

Some attributes are directly mapped to properties and vice versa, but this is not always the case.

For instance, the `onClick` attribute takes a string that is then `eval`'d, but the `onclick` property takes a function. This is why your code isn't working.

Either pass a valid function, or use `setAttribute`.

Comment: While I understand what you're doing here, I'm unsure how to implement this in my case. While the onclick or onClicks aren't working, my questions remains as to why these aren't even written to the page while the other attributes are.

Comment: Because, as I just said, not all properties and attributes are directly linked.

Comment: Could you provide additional insight as to how I can get it working? I don't understand what I need to do, which I attempted to indicate in my previous comment.

Comment: Use `setAttribute`. Instead of `element.property = x`, use `element.setAttribute('property',x);`

Comment: Okay, I got this working, but it oddly only works on the first button in the list. Off to pose a new question. My new line was `btnN.setattribute('onclick', btn_D );`

Comment: Additional follow-up: I discovered how to get the links working in FF, IE and Chrome. I need to include 2 methods as such:     `btnN.setAttribute('onClick', btn_D );
btnN.onClick = function() { btn_D };
`

Answer (score 0):

You are setting onclick with a string, it needs a function to execute.

```
createbutton("button01", 1, "New Order/Browse",  function(){ parent.frames['content'].location.href='createorder/createorder.asp'; });
```

Comment: That will get the wrong `parent`. It'll get the `parent` of the context in which you're calling `createbutton`, rather than the `parent` in the context of the frame on which the button click happened.